# Django with DRF and OAUTH2.0

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, jwt

I'm trying development a system with Django and **[Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/)**, since i started i found out two problem, first for authentication second for permissions, i want use **OAuth2.0** to make it possible, and [django-oauth-toolkit](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Now, i wanna know how i authenticate a user and give the right for his, if he is *admin* or *normal* user?

Comment: what code have you tried?

Comment: i don't understand?

Comment: what code i have tried, i tried using react as frontend, django as backend, DRF for RestAPI, oauth for authentications,etc...